# Load Wordpress block when scrolled to its position

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scroll, triggers

On my wordpress.com homepage I have a code block that loads a JavaScript animation. However the animation starts running when the page is loading even though the block is further down on the page (not visible when scrolled to the top).

Is it possible to set a trigger to load the block/trigger the javascript when the user Scrolls down to this specific area of the homepage?

I am novice to html and javascript so I have not found any solution. Tried googling but only found triggers when scrolling down to bottom of page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way is [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

```js
let elementToObserve = document.querySelector('selector');

let options = {
  threshold: 1.0, // 100% of element to appear on screen, 0.9 -> 90%, etc.
  // also here could be root and rootMargin, see Docs
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, options);

observer.observe(elementToObserve);

function handleIntersection(entries) {
  entries.map((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      alert('Visible!!');
      // Here you can execute your JS code
      observer.unobserve(elementToObserve);
    }
  });
}
```